# Starting letter on a new page when \begin{letter} is called

Tags: formatting, pdftex, letters

here is my latex code.

```
\newenvironment{namesection}[3]{
    \centering
    {
        \sffamily
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\fontsize{40pt}{10cm}\selectfont #1 
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
        \par
    }
    \vspace{5pt}
    \centering
    { 
        \color{headings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3
        \par
    }
}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,hyperref}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}
\signature{James A. Abrahamson}
\address{}
\begin{document}
\begin{namesection}{James A.}{Abrahamson}
{
        \href{mailto:teletubby@gmail.com}{teletubby@gmail.com} 
        | +44 90078601  \\ 
        Teletubby Land
}
\end{namesection}
\bigskip
\hrule
\begin{letter}{Recruitment \\ Morgan Stanley \\ 25 Cabot Square \\ Canary Wharf \\ London, UK }
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
Hello, Letter Content.
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\end{letter}
%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The letter always begins on a new page, but I want it to begin on the same page.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I almost downvoted your question for the use of "Teletubby" LOL!

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get your MWE to compile.  So I could not propose a fix.

Comment: Its not compilable, I posted a section of the code.

Comment: It is standard procedure to post a full minimum **working** example, both to save the time of those who would otherwise help you, as well as to remove all doubt about document class and package dependencies.

Comment: Can you compile now? I did post a full minimum working example for you, thank you so much. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: No, I am sorry.  I still cannot compile.

Comment: You have to compile in same document as XeLatex.

Comment: I'm not sure the font font is related to the page break, and thus can be removed along with fontspec and friends. The break presumably comes from the stuff you add before the begin-letter part. AFAIR letter starts with a clear page, so since there is something on the page (the rule) it starts a new page. Btw: make your mwe fully testable to or Thera so the can copy the code as is, and test without having to add or change anything. Basically making it selfcontained.

Comment: How can I make letter not start on a new page? thats the exact issue I am having, yes.

Comment: just put your `namesection` in the first page head  (define `pagestyle` for the first page).

Answer (score 1):

`tikz` to the rescue!  I just added a background image to the top.  You can move it elsewhere as you see fit. I changed the fonts since I don't have them.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref}
\signature{James A. Abrahamson}
\newenvironment{namesection}[3]{
    \centering
    {
        \sffamily
        \fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\fontsize{40pt}{10cm}\selectfont #1 
        \fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\selectfont #2
        \par
    }
    \vspace{5pt}
    \centering
    { 
        \color{blue}\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3
        \par
    }
}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    

\begin{letter}{Recruitment \\ Morgan Stanley \\ 25 Cabot Square \\ Canary Wharf \\ London, UK } 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north)}]
\node[align=center,anchor=north]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{namesection}{James A.}{Abrahamson}
        {
            \href{mailto:teletubby@gmail.com}{teletubby@gmail.com} 
            | +44 900 78601  \\ 
            Teletubby Land
        }
        \end{namesection}
        \bigskip
        \hrule}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}


Hello, Letter Content.
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\end{letter}
%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the begin{letter} not begin on a new page?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but in my example everything is on the same page, as you want, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as you wanted.....

All I did was to copy the code for the letter environment from `letter.cls` and remove the `\newpage` command.

This may well produce undesired side effects: caveat emptor.

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}




\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{letter}[1]
  {
    \if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
                \else\thispagestyle{empty}\null\newpage\fi
    \fi
    \c@page \@ne
    \c@footnote \z@
    \interlinepenalty=200 % smaller than the TeXbook value
    \@processto{\leavevmode\ignorespaces #1}}
  {\stopletter\@@par\pagebreak\@@par
    \if@filesw
      \begingroup
        \let\\=\relax
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \immediate\write\@auxout{%
          \string\@mlabel{\returnaddress}{\toname\\\toaddress}}%
      \endgroup
    \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\signature{Me}
\address{}
\begin{letter}{My mom}
    \opening{Dear Mom,}

\closing{See ya!}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Pretty much what I wanted but still wanting to reduce white space on the top.

Comment: You can use your code for that, or mine in my other answer.